# Restructuring Array of Tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

I have an array of tuples of tuples where the second level should not be a tuple and I want to convert it all to something like a 2-d array. 
Is there a quick way to restructure from this messy 1-d to a nice clean 2-d or structured array?

Note: These tuples **do** contain various types. I would like to be able to transpose and 2-d slice etc.. this data.

ie...

```
[((1,-4,7.0),)
((2,-5,8.0),)
((3,-6,9.0),)]
```

*Edited to try and accommodate issues people pointed out with the original question*

Comment: Is this how your array really looks? Looks you have tuples and not extra dimensions.

Comment: Sorry Yes this is the structure the print statement spits out. I suppose it is an array of tuples of tuples? AKA there is no fancy way to convert this?

Comment: What's the shape and dtype?

Comment: Is that really *exactly* what is printed out?  I.e. did you copy-and-paste that into stackoverflow?  Numpy arrays do not capitalize the name `array` in their string representation.

Comment: Ah! Yes thank you - this particular example happens to be shape : (2271824L,) (so one dimension) but they dtype is very complex. I suppose this points me to the answer - 'it's complicated'. Thank you!

Comment: To warren: No I added the 'Array' which was silly. I will remove it. The formatting was otherwise copied as the actual content is complex. I see now that that was a poor choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.squeeze](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

`np.squeeze(<your array>)`

Answer (score 0):

The `dtype` is important here.  The closest I can come to your display is with a nested dtype

```
In [182]: dt1=np.dtype('i,i,f')
In [183]: dt=np.dtype([('a',dt1,),('b',dt1,),('c',dt1,)])

In [184]: x=np.ones(1,dtype=dt)

In [185]: print(x)
[((1, 1, 1.0), (1, 1, 1.0), (1, 1, 1.0))]
```

(no final `,`)

If I use the `repr` rather than print's default `str`, I see the dtype as well:

```
In [186]: print(repr(x))
array([((1, 1, 1.0), (1, 1, 1.0), (1, 1, 1.0))], 
      dtype=[('a', [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')]), ('b', [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')]), ('c', [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4')])])
```

Reshape or squeeze does not work here because it is already 1d.  `view` or `astype` can work.  Do you want to just flatten the dtype, or make it all float?  What kind of shape do you expect?  Currently each record consists of 9 numbers.

With a compatible dtype I can view this array as a record of 9 values:

```
In [195]: dt2=np.dtype('i,i,f,i,i,f,i,i,f')
In [196]: x.view(dt2)
Out[196]: 
array([(1, 1, 1.0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1, 1, 1.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<f4'), ('f6', '<i4'), ('f7', '<i4'), ('f8', '<f4')])
```

The simplest way to turn this `x` into an array of floats is with `tolist` (it's not fastest):

```
In [256]: x['c']=(20,21,22)
In [257]: x['b']=(10,11,12)
In [258]: x['a']=(1,2,3)

In [263]: print(x)
[((1, 2, 3.0), (10, 11, 12.0), (20, 21, 22.0))]
In [264]: np.array(x.tolist())
Out[264]: 
array([[[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [ 10.,  11.,  12.],
        [ 20.,  21.,  22.]]])
```